# How to use replace mode for python

Tags: python

There is a sample of regx:
"one two"  use this regx to \b(\w+)(\s)(\w+)\b replace with $3$2$1 and then get "two one"
Now i want to implement this with python re.sub:

```
s="one two"
print re.sub(r"\b(\w+)(\s)(\w+)\b","$3$2$1",s)
```

This output $3$2$1, not "two one".How can i do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `\number` in python for printing a matched result:

```
>>> s="one two"
>>> print re.sub(r"\b(\w+)(\s)(\w+)\b",r"\3\2\1",s)
two one
```

Note that you have to make it a raw string, or you would have to do `\\3 \\2 \\1` (i.e escape the backslashes)

Comment: if i use this regx, then what it should be ?   `"\b(?P<word1>\w+)(\s)(?P<word2>\w+)\b"`

Comment: @jimwan It looks like you're grouping three things, so shouldn't it just be `\3\2\1`?

Comment: i want to use group name such as word1, word2. This not work ${word2}${word1}

Comment: @jimwan I don't know if I 100% understand what you're saying, but `r"\1 \3"` ?

Comment: yes, \3\2\1 works. But i want to use this `re.sub(r"\b(?P<word1>\w+)(\s)(?P<word2>\w+)\b",r"{word2} {word1}",s)` for the same function as `print re.sub(r"\b(\w+)(\s)(\w+)\b",r"\3\2\1",s)`

Comment: @jimwan You can't use names to access grouped elements. You have to use `\number`

Comment: i find the solution. This works for me. `print re.sub(r"\b(?P<word1>\w+)(\s)(?P<word2>\w+)\b",r"\g<word2> \g<word1>",s)`